# Protoc C# Google Assistant .proto "Was Not Found Or Has Errors"

Tags: c#, grpc, proto, google-assistant-sdk

I want to communicate with the Google Assistant SDK using gRPC. I downloaded the embedded_assistant.proto and ran this command in CMD:

```
protoc -I=I:"\PC Folders\Downloads\proto3.3.0win32\bin" --csharp_out=$DST_DIR "I:\PC Folders\Downloads\proto3.3.0win32\bin\embedded_assistant.proto"
```

It then gave me these errors:

> google/api/annotations.proto: File not found.
>   google/rpc/status.proto: File not found.
>   embedded_assistant.proto: Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors.
>   embedded_assistant.proto: Import "google/rpc/status.proto" was not found or had errors.
>   embedded_assistant.proto:270:5: "google.rpc.Status" is not defined.

How can I fix this? I used this proto compiler: https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases and at the bottom where it says protoc-3.3.0-win32.zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get those file from the [googleapis/googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) repository:

- [google/rpc/status.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/status.proto)
- [google/api/annotations.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/annotations.proto)

Comment: I had downloaded those files but it turns out I had to put it into the include folder not the bin folder. Thanks for your help :)