# Protoc 3.9 Compiled Output for C# Fails

Tags: c#, google-assistant-sdk, protoc

Runtime environment: .net core 2.2 , same issue for .net framework 4.6.1

While trying to create gRPC bindings for C# for Google Assistant SDK, in EmbeddedAssistant.g.cs am getting compile time error 
"Cannot Convert from System.Type to Google.Type"

**Project Available for Download**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pbmg0Zk-ozXHkWT6a6FMmBt79MTHn7_t/view?usp=sharing

i am also getting errors on Google.Protobuf that

"Type" is a namespace but is used like a type.

#### **Details**

I followed [instructions to integrate google assistant for C# (Other languages: gRPC)](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/integrate)

1. [clone Google APIs on local disk](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.9.0)
2. I downloaded  [Protoc Compiler latest release](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.9.0)
3. Followed instructions to generate EmbeddedAssistant.g.cs file
4. Earlier it was throwing error that Google.Protobuf.Collections and Google.Protobuf.Reflection are not available, so i downloaded **protobuf-csharp-3.9.0.zip** from link at #2 , copied Google.Protobuf folder in my project folder, that error went way.
5. For Google.API and Google.Type Errors, i followed this  [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013299/protoc-c-sharp-google-assistant-proto-was-not-found-or-has-errors)  and it was resolved.

Compiled Output where the error is :

```
   descriptor = pbr::FileDescriptor.FromGeneratedCode(descriptorData,
          new pbr::FileDescriptor[] { global::Google.Api.AnnotationsReflection.Descriptor, global::Google.Type.LatlngReflection.Descriptor, },
          new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(null, null, new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo[] {
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AssistRequest), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AssistRequest.Parser, new[]{ "Config", "AudioIn" }, new[]{ "Type" }, null, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AssistResponse), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AssistResponse.Parser, new[]{ "EventType", "AudioOut", "ScreenOut", "DeviceAction", "SpeechResults", "DialogStateOut", "DebugInfo" }, null, new[]{ typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AssistResponse.Types.EventType) }, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DebugInfo), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DebugInfo.Parser, new[]{ "AogAgentToAssistantJson" }, null, null, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AssistConfig), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AssistConfig.Parser, new[]{ "AudioInConfig", "TextQuery", "AudioOutConfig", "ScreenOutConfig", "DialogStateIn", "DeviceConfig", "DebugConfig" }, new[]{ "Type" }, null, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AudioInConfig), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AudioInConfig.Parser, new[]{ "Encoding", "SampleRateHertz" }, null, new[]{ typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AudioInConfig.Types.Encoding) }, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AudioOutConfig), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AudioOutConfig.Parser, new[]{ "Encoding", "SampleRateHertz", "VolumePercentage" }, null, new[]{ typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AudioOutConfig.Types.Encoding) }, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.ScreenOutConfig), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.ScreenOutConfig.Parser, new[]{ "ScreenMode" }, null, new[]{ typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.ScreenOutConfig.Types.ScreenMode) }, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DialogStateIn), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DialogStateIn.Parser, new[]{ "ConversationState", "LanguageCode", "DeviceLocation", "IsNewConversation" }, null, null, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DeviceConfig), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DeviceConfig.Parser, new[]{ "DeviceId", "DeviceModelId" }, null, null, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AudioOut), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AudioOut.Parser, new[]{ "AudioData" }, null, null, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.ScreenOut), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.ScreenOut.Parser, new[]{ "Format", "Data" }, null, new[]{ typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.ScreenOut.Types.Format) }, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DeviceAction), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DeviceAction.Parser, new[]{ "DeviceRequestJson" }, null, null, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.SpeechRecognitionResult), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.SpeechRecognitionResult.Parser, new[]{ "Transcript", "Stability" }, null, null, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DialogStateOut), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DialogStateOut.Parser, new[]{ "SupplementalDisplayText", "ConversationState", "MicrophoneMode", "VolumePercentage" }, null, new[]{ typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DialogStateOut.Types.MicrophoneMode) }, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DebugConfig), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DebugConfig.Parser, new[]{ "ReturnDebugInfo" }, null, null, null, null),
            new pbr::GeneratedClrTypeInfo(typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DeviceLocation), global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.DeviceLocation.Parser, new[]{ "Coordinates" }, new[]{ "Type" }, null, null, null)
          }));
    }
```

**Compiler Error on compiled output of EmbeddedAssistant.g.cs line 101 to 116**

and **Compiler error on Google.Protobuf ReflectionUtil.cs on Type 
Type is a namespace but used like a type.**

```
 internal static readonly Type[] EmptyTypes = new Type[0];

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a delegate which will cast the argument to the type that declares the method,
        /// call the method on it, then convert the result to object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="method">The method to create a delegate for, which must be declared in an IMessage
        /// implementation.</param>
        internal static Func<IMessage, object> CreateFuncIMessageObject(MethodInfo method) =>
            GetReflectionHelper(method.DeclaringType, method.ReturnType).CreateFuncIMessageObject(method);
```

[C# Project Structure. Files under Google folder /API , /Assistant and /Type were generated by Protoc 3.9.0 compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM0AF.png)

[Errors look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRHS9.png)

Comment: **Error1**

first parameter of GeneratedClrTypeInfo is throwing error 

`typeof(global::Google.Assistant.Embedded.V1Alpha2.AssistRequest)`

 **Error: Cannot convert from System.Type to Google.Type**


**Error 2** : 

** Google.Protobuf.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.cs  Line # 75 onwards **


**Error: Type is a namespace but used like a type**

Comment: issue i posted on protocol buffer github repo 
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6388

Answer (score 1):

**ISSUE RESOLVED**

i used this link 
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md

basically added minimum necessary .proto files from googleapis to make google assistant work. Image attached

[Screenshot of what project looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGqa3.png)

then added **Grpc , Grpc.Tools nuget package, followed instructions in above article to change .csproj and built it.**

i just added following in my csproj

```
<Protobuf Include="**/*.proto" OutputDir="%(RelativePath)"/>
```

**It generated the output shown in image**

Build was failing but CS files were generated.
Take the generated CS files , add them to your real project and add **Google.Protobuf nuget package** , build and you're good to go.